# How do I draw text with UnicodeFont with Slick?

Tags: java, slick2d

I need to know how to draw text with **UnicodeFont** and **Slick**.
I don't want to make a class that extends by BasicGame or BasicGameState, I just want to implement it straight into my main-class.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the JavaDoc of UnicodeFont, as located [here](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/UnicodeFont.html), gives you a few methods called 'drawString'. Note that you don't need any reference to any of the other Slick classes.

Now, if that's not sufficient, there's a tutorial on the LWJGL wiki [here](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Slick-Util_Library_-_Part_3_-_TrueType_Fonts_for_LWJGL) which is about fonts using Slick-Util. In the tutorial TrueTypeFont is used, but UnicodeFont should work the same way.